# Accessing error data from forms

Tags: forms, session

I am trying to re apply user information to forms which they have incorrectly completed.

Current steps of the form:

1 - user is presented with form

2 - user enters data

3 - user submits data

4 - data is validated

- - data is unsuccessful
- - error message is set
- - error message is passed to session
- - error message is displayed above form
- - **users inputted data is not reapplied to form**

5 - data is saved

6 - user is passed to relevant page

The line in bold is what I need to change, I have been unable to work how to reapply the users data in to the fields. Do I need to change the block I am referencing, if so to what? I have tried a few options.

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="prefs_new" as="prefs_new" template="ps/prefs/new.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

In the phtml file I have tried `$this->getSession()` but returned an error, I have also `var_dump()` the model, but could not see the data in there, where am I going wrong. I know I need to apply the data to each field individually, I just cannot work out how to get the required data in the first place.

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getParam('your_field_name')` or `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` will get the form field from the POST data. You'll probably need to grab the POST data in your controller and pass it along to your block.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but had needed to pass the post data again, I thought it was stored in a session, my only problem now is displaying the values in the drop down menu's, the text boxes work fine, just those pesky drop downs

Answer (score 3):

When an error occurs, save the date sent through post in the session then apply it to the form.
Store in session

```
$data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setPostedData($data);
```

Then, if the form is built using `Varien_Form` just add this at the end of the form:

```
$data = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getPostedData(true); //the parameter true removes it from session
$form->addValues($data);
```

If the form is built in a phtml file just check if there is something posted for each field.

```
<?php $data = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getPostedData(true); //at the top of the file?>
```

Now for each input do this:

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="<?php echo (isset($data['some_name']) ? $data['some_name'] : '') ?>"
```

Comment: Marius, i thought ,will be better to use core/session  instead of customer/session

Comment: I don't think there is a big difference. You can use the core session if you want. but may I ask why? Maybe there is something I'm missing?